# Should delete be followed by commit if add command is next?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, session, sqlalchemy

On sqlalchemy flask python3 mysql project, which one is best? Commit twice:

```
Investments.query.filter(Investments.investment_id == current_user.uid).delete()
db.session.commit()
investments = Investments(bond=None,quantity=0,investment_id=current_user.uid)
db.session.add(investments)
db.session.commit()
```

or only 1 commit:

```
Investments.query.filter(Investments.investment_id == current_user.uid).delete()
investments = Investments(bond=None,quantity=0,investment_id=current_user.uid)
db.session.add(investments)
db.session.commit()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html does not give a definitive answer but some guidelines.

Comment: "It depends", are those 2 things such that they must either happen together, or not happen at all?

Comment: Yes, either both go or none gets executed

Comment: Then the latter is correct, since both the delete and insert of the new record take place in the same transaction and are committed together.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä. It resonates with the examples that https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html brings (with dos and dont's)

Answer (score 0):

A commit ensures these happen all at the same time and are all rolled back if there is an error. The question is thus whether you want these operations to be grouped together or not.

If, for example, the second operation fails, would you like that the first one be rolled back as well? If so, do one commit. If not, do two commits.

Note this question is not specific to Flask, Python or MySQL; it’s a common question when you use any type of transactional database.